# ssh Bad configuration option: host

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

Try to set up ssh with this instructions: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

get the following error:

```
user@iMac-user dir % ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
/Users/bitbucket-user/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: host
/Users/bitbucket-user/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

config file contains only 2 rows as described:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
```

ssh -V:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

What I missed? It should be pretty simple i think.